# SURF_CUDA every execution compute different keypoints

Tags: opencv, surf, homography

I have a question concerning the SURF_CUDA algorirthm. I want to detect the features of some frames in order to stitch them in the end. Therefore I need to compute the keypoints and descriptors. But the results are different on every execution, although the images are the same. How is that possible?
I checked if the keypoints position are changing on every execution and I figured out they do change, even if its not a big change. But because of that I get different results for Homography.
Does someone know how to stabilze the algorithm?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `cv2.setRNGSeed(0)` at the beginning of your code. There is no guarantee that it's going to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the matches solved the problem.  The results were being returned in different a different order on every execution.